# Can't change purple theme on Wordpress - Footer, Header, Navigation, etc

Tags: wordpress, styles, themes, footer

I've tried everything and can't seem to change the theme colors on this site to a deep black rather than purple.

It has a child and parent theme with two style sheets. I've inspected all the code elements and the code in the style sheets. And the code for the footer: rgb(107, 34, 98) doesn't exist anywhere in the editor on any pages. It's simply not there. I've searched for it. It's not there.

Where could it be hiding?

https://www.hawaiianmanagement.com/

Comment: change in style.css to : #footer-columns {
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

Comment: style.css is here:  https://www.hawaiianmanagement.com/wp-content/themes/parkcity-f/style.css

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Is it possible that the theme is corrupt?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the fonts. They aren't responding to changes either.

Comment: Make sure to clear cache, it's black on my pc.

Comment: Oh! It worked! Thanks!